# why is flash apk file different from java apk file

Tags: java, android, air, apk, flash-cs6

What is different about a flash apk file (for android mobile) compared to a java apk file?

When you install a flash-generated apk file from the google play store, it requires adobe air; so apparently the flash-generated apk file is not of the same form as a java-generated file.

Comment: Don't know about the differences but when you publish AIR for android, you have the option to include AIR runtime.  If you include the runtime, the app doesn't need AIR to be installed.  When you publish to IOS, you have to include the AIR runtime.

Comment: true, but it adds about 11MB to the app

Comment: Yes.  It adds AIR runtime which is about 10mb.  You were asking about size?  Not about the actual file contents?  Or are you asking about authoring environment?

Comment: I am just wondering why one .apk is different from another ... the one generated by flash obviously is not complete, otherwise it wouldn't need AIR ... why doesn't flash compile its AS3 into an .apk that is the same as an .apk generated by JAVA code in Eclipse (as example).

Comment: Having it separate is good OO design.  AIR was supposed to be a separate download like a player.  That way AIR could be updated and all the applications using it wouldn't have to be - when devices update only AIR would have to update, not your app.  Flash takes one set of code and deploys to IOS, Android, desktop, flash player, HTML5 canvas, etc.

Comment: I appreciate all that ... but a JAVA-generated app simply works, without the user having to worry about any third-party add-ons ... the same logic as why people prefer html5 in the browser vs flash player (no third-party add-ons needed)

Comment: ... but my question is really `what is different about the code that flash generates during compiling, such that when android reads it, android goes 'oh, man, you'll need an add-on to run that code'` ... in other words, why is it not simply readable like all of the other apps?

Comment: Already answered that one.  People don't prefer HTML, it's what was here before Apple, Microsoft, and Google.